# Python library IP2location Backtrack

Tags: python, linux

I'm having trouble installing this library.

Here is the sites official guide:

- Download IP2Location C library at here.
- Decompress C library.
- `tar ip2location-c-x.x.x.tar.gz`
- Download and decompress Python library.
- `tar ip2location-python-x.x.x.tar.gz`
- Get into working directory.
- `cd ip2location-python-x.x.x`
- Edit `setup.py` to point `library_dirs` and `include_dirs` ponting to IP2Location C library folder.
- Start compilation.
- `python setup.py build && python setup.py install`

so I move both into `/home/usr/ip2loc` dir and run the `tar -zxvf` and then move into the C dir.
From there I follow the README to install and get things going. I then move to the python dir and dont know how/where to link the setup.py. Thats my current problem.

I know I need to alter the path of the `library_dirs` and `include_dirs` but I dont know where to link those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`easy_install` invokes `setup.py`, which will respect a setup.cfg file in the distribution it's trying to install.

Add following in `setup.cfg`

```
[build_ext]
include_dirs = /path/to/headers
library_dirs = /path/to/libs
```

[How to setup.cfg](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/configfile.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, im no realizing there are errors with the C building (Despite following README and the INSTALL verbatim) but thats something ill have to trouble shoot. Thanks for help once I get the C library properly built ill make sure to put this to the test. Thanks again!